# ActiveX TextBox cannot appear in outlook. Will show a big red cross instead

Tags: email, outlook, ms-word, activex

I did a table in word documents and in order to limit the number of words, I put ActiveX text box in it.

[image: ActiveX textbox in words]

However this table will need to be sent to email (Outlook) and usually, the standard or practice is to copy and paste the table into the Microsoft outlook. When i copy and paste the table into outlook, there will be a big red cross:

[image: Textbox in outlook]

What can I do so that it will show the name and not the BIG RED X?

Much appreciated for the help

Tried using other textboxes but is either they cant limit the number of characters or they restrict editing from others.

Comment: If you copy and paste the Word built-in objects directly into Outlook, it will certainly cause this result. The big red cross means it can't find the corresponding object, because it's only available in Word. If you paste it into Word and try it, it should not be a big red cross anymore. You can either send the Word file you made as an attachment, or see if there are similar objects in Outlook that can be used, and these objects can also be displayed in the recipient's computer, otherwise, it is the same in vain. You can also consider using a Google or Microsoft Form to make a similar table.